# How do I linearize such a constraint?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, linearization

I was wondering, how one would linearize such a constraint, to make it applicable to LPs.

$ a_{i}=(a_{i-1}+b_{i})(1-c_{i})-d_{i}$

$a_i$ gives information of the number of assigned jobs to machine $i$. $b_i$ if machine $i$ performs a job. $c_i$ indicates whether a machine breaks down. $d_i$ if a job is finished.

Comment: Can you please tell us, what are your decision variables and are they continuous, binary etc.?

Comment: Just updated the OP!

Comment: Your constraint enforces $a_i=-d_i$ when $c_i=1$.  Is that really what you want?  From your description, it sounds like $a_i$ is a nonnegative integer and $d_i$ is binary, so that would mean that $a_i=0=d_i$.

Comment: @manofthousandnames, I am unsure I understand what exactly you mean by defining such a constraint. If $a_i$ is defined as the number of assigned jobs to machine $i$, and also $a_{i-1}$ is referred to the number of assigned jobs to machine $i-1$, then suppose $a_{i-1} = 5$, $b_{i} = 1$, $c_{i} = 0$, and $d_{i} = 1$ then $a_{i} = (5+1).(1) - 1 = 5$. In this manner, the number of assigned jobs to machine $i$ would be $5$, which is incorrect!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, $c_i$ is a binary decision variable that is $1$ if machine $i$ breaks down and $0$ otherwise. Also, I assume that $(a_{i-1}+b_i)$ is non-negative. You can introduce the decision variable $z$ which takes the value of $(a_{i-1}+b_i)(1-c_i)$. You can then introduce the following constraints.

\begin{align}
a_{i}=z-d_{i}\newline
0 \leq z \leq a_{i-1}+b_i \newline
z \geq (a_{i-1}+b_i)-c_iM \newline
z \leq M(1−c_i)
\end{align}

The first two constraints are straightforward. In the third constraint, if the machine does not break down, i.e., $c_i = 0$, $z$ is forced to take value $a_{i-1}+b_i$. If the machine breaks down ($c_i = 1$), the RHS becomes negative (where $M$ is a large number) and $z$ will take value $0$, because of the fourth constraint.

Comment: Well thought of, Peter

Comment: One thing is if $c_i=0$, no enforcement for $z_i=0$, so need a constraint like $0 \le z_i \le M(1-c_i)$

Comment: @SutanuMajumdar I dont believe that is needed. If $c_i = 0$,  we have $z \geq a_{i−1}+b_i$ (third constraint) and through the second constraint, $z \leq a_{i−1}+b_i$ still holds. Therefore, $z$ must become $a_{i−1}+b_i$.

Comment: The $c_i=1$ case is what still needs to be enforced, and the suggestion by @SutanuMajumdar does that.

Comment: Oh yes, now I see it. I will add that to my answer. Thanks @RobPratt and Sutanu Majumdar.